# Trigger for multiple table

Tags: oracle, triggers, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need to create a trigger that dont let enter dates before the actual date in all the tables of the database.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER t_date
    BEFORE INSERT ON ?
    FOR EACH ROW
```

So how can i refer to all the tables that have DATE as data type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.

A trigger can be defined on only one table.  If you want to enforce the rule on every table in the schema, you would need to create a separate trigger on each table in the schema.